# WFFM Captcha Image not loaded on CD

Tags: wffm, content-delivery

I'm using `Web Forms for Marketers 9.0 rev. 171003`.

Below is what loaded in CD
[image]

I did add this under `web.config`,

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
<add name="CaptchaImage" verb="*" path="CaptchaImage.axd" type="Sitecore.Form.Core.Pipeline.RequestProcessor.CaptchaResolver, Sitecore.Forms.Core" />
<add name="CaptchaAudio" verb="*" path="CaptchaAudio.axd" type="Sitecore.Form.Core.Pipeline.RequestProcessor.CaptchaResolver, Sitecore.Forms.Core" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

but the image is still not loaded and I did get a 404 error.

[image]

Did I miss something?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99969/discussion-on-question-by-andiyangita-w-wffm-captcha-image-not-loaded-on-cd).